# Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate - Coded UI Test Builder: Method not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I switched from using the selenium webdriver & visual studio 2013 basic for my automated tests to Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 and Coded UI.
So I created a new coded UI test project and started recording my actions. But when I click generate code, I always get this error that prevents the code to be generated and added to the project:

`Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.SqmUtility.StopSession(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.SessionResult)'.`

Any idea why or how to deal with it?

Comment: Have you updated your VS2012 ultimate with last VS Update package? Googling for this message it shows that somebody fix this message only installing Update 1...

Comment: Looks like installing the latest update (4) did the trick, thank you!